# Rails running on virtual machine in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, virtual-machine

The reason why I want to switch to Ubuntu is that people said that GEMS works better on Linux than on Windows.

I don't want to get a MacBook Pro just for Rails development since I love Windows and I cannot stand the lack of apps for Mac. Moreover, people are saying that Ubuntu is "better" than Mac: http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1bgj1s/are_there_advantages_of_ubuntu_over_os_x_for/

Does Virtual Box work well enough that it doesn't have any lag at all? I am using i7-3517U CPU with 8GB memory. I need to program in an environment that is lag-free and not sluggish. Or are there any alternatives to recommend?

I am unsure about all the permission settings or any complicated stuffs regarding the terminal. But I'll be using the terminal to develop. I'm still quite new here for development in Linux. Please be kind to me >< Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@holyxiaoxin I am pretty sure you should be asking this on [superuser](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Nevertheless, I would suggest you to install Ubuntu in a partition instead of running a Virtual Machine. Here's a guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Also, yes. Developing in a virtual machine could be very accurate, but at the end you could experiment weird behaviour when working with native libs mostly and you will be wondering if it is the VM or your setup.

Hope this help you get started. Also [Ubuntu and Ruby on rails](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm)

P.S. I use OSX and it's the best you can get for RoR and development environments. Think about it as an investment to the future.

Answer (score 1):

@holyxiaoxin hi. I have only ran rails on windows and Mac. Me personally I just got a MacBook pro. In my opinion Mac makes my life easier when it comes to rails development plus I am learning xcode and swift at the same time. I feel like you have to jump through hoops and ladders to fix certain errors and install gems on windows such as paperclip and even public activity. Yes it does help you with your skills in debugging but it slows down the learning process. Not only that but Mac is a faster development environment. I am not an expert but I just wanted to give you my personal experience if that is okay. I love windows as well and it makes me sad playing on my Mac while my windows is sitting over there but I still use my windows for things like packet tracer(which I haven't done in forever since discovering rails) Python, and writing essays and learning visual studios

Comment: "Not only that but Mac is a faster development environment."
In what way is Mac a faster development environment? Could you elaborate? Thanks. (:

Comment: @holyxiaoxin reason why Mac has a faster development environment is because of brew, gems,and other bash commands that are friendly when it comes to interaction with a rails environment. These command line tools do most if not all the work for you when installing gems to you rails application. Windows however is not so fortunate . They may require you to play in folders you should not be playing with and could slow down production when loading a rails application  Even rbenv speeds up the development of rails application by allowing you to switch to different versions of ruby and rails.

Comment: @holyxiaoxin also all the tutorials that I have done uses a Mac. The only tutorial that I have seen that does not use a mac is the tutorial in understanding the basics of ruby on youtube. So when you run into an error on windows and they are using a mac for a tutorial, and the error they get is simple while yours is complicated, believe me it will make you have a headache. I once took a break from rails and almost gave up when I was running into an error every corner. Of course when you understand the MVC pattern more it can help with errors but its not always the case. I hope I did well :)